# Switching Ruby on Rails to use Aurora's writer instance on Devise password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

To my understanding, the RoR app switches between reader and writer instances based on the HTTP verb. However, there are some cases where a GET request should go to a writer instance instead of the reader instance.

For example, when sending an email to a user for a password reset, the email includes a link that obviously triggers an HTTP GET request. When the user submits that GET request, the following happens on my RoR server:

```
I, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.002075 #192]  INFO -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82] Started GET "/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=[FILTERED]" for 98.252.220.17 at 2023-02-09 01:13:04 +0000
D, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.002353 #192] DEBUG -- sentry: [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82] [Tracing] Discarding <rails.request> transaction </users/password/edit> because it's not included in the random sample (sampling rate = 0.05)
I, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.007959 #192]  INFO -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82] Processing by Users::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
I, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.008016 #192]  INFO -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]   Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
D, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.008472 #192] DEBUG -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82] Connected to the writing database
D, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.008716 #192] DEBUG -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82] Finished executing edit action
D, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.013578 #192] DEBUG -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]   Rendering layout layouts/devise.html.erb
D, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.013677 #192] DEBUG -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]   Rendering devise/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/devise
I, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.014048 #192]  INFO -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]   Rendered devise/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/devise (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 113)
I, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.017889 #192]  INFO -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]   Rendered layout layouts/devise.html.erb (Duration: 4.2ms | Allocations: 1271)
I, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.018122 #192]  INFO -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2313)
F, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.019093 #192] FATAL -- : [e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]   
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82] ActionView::Template::Error (Write query attempted while in readonly mode: INSERT INTO "sessions" ("session_id", "data", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"):
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]     2: <html>
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]     3: <head>
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]     4:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]     5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]     6:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]     7: 
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]     8:     <% domain = URI.parse(request.original_url).host %>
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82]   
[e239d05c-705a-4e30-8b33-2106c6deef82] app/views/layouts/devise.html.erb:5
I, [2023-02-09T01:13:04.032139 #192]  INFO -- sentry: [Transport] Sending envelope
```

I am specifically using a custom `PasswordsController` for devise to modify the instance for the `edit` action:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Users
  class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
    include UserConcern
    ...
    def edit
      ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :writing) do
        super
      end
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

However, the issue seems to be when the `app/views/layouts/devise.html.erb` file loads.  I've narrowed down the sessions INSERT statement happens here:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

```
[6] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007fbf7ed9a9f0>>)> csrf_meta_tags
ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyError: Write query attempted while in readonly mode: INSERT INTO "sessions" ("session_id", "data", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"                                                      
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:120:in `check_if_write_query'                                                                                                           
[7] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007fbf7ed9a9f0>>)> exit
```

Is there any way that I can load the csrf_meta_tags but while connected to the writer instance?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that's going to go through this battle, I ended up solving this by wrapping my devise forms in the following way:

```
# app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb
<% ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: writing) %>
   -- password reset form goes here --
<% end %>
```

Wrapping the `edit` method in the `PasswordsController` to override the Devise `edit` method didn't do the trick because the form is rendered after the `edit` method is executed, but wrapping the HTML form did.